# C# Number Triangle Ascending and Descending by 2

Tags: c#, for-loop, nested-loops

I found a way to display the top half of the triangle ending at 18 with a nested for loop. I cannot figure out how to display the bottom half in a nested for loop as well (it has to be in a nested for loop). Also, how to make the the colors interchange from green and red? Any tips?

[image]

Here's what I have:

```
int n1, n2, n3;

// Top Triangle nested for loop
for (n1 = 2; n1 <=18; n1++)
{
    for (n2 = 2; n2 <= n1; n2++)
    {
        Console.Write("{0} ", n2);
        n2++;
    }
    n1++;
    Console.WriteLine();
}

// Bottom triangle nested for loop
// This is where I'm stuck
```

Comment: Is that picture your desired behavior or a screenshot of what you've already done?

Comment: It's the desired behavior.

Comment: You should check out the [`Console.SetCursorPosition`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.setcursorposition(v=vs.110).aspx) method and the [`Console.ForegroundColor`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.foregroundcolor%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        for (n1 = 2; n1 <= 18; n1++)
        {
            for (n2 = 2; n2 <= n1; n2++)
            {
                Console.Write("{0} ", n2);
                n2++;
            }
            n1++;
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
        for (n1 = 2; n1 <= 18; n1++)
        {
            for (n2 = 2; n2 <= 18 - n1; n2++)
            {
                Console.Write("{0} ", n2);
                n2++;
            }
            n1++;
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Bottom triangle section :

```
  // Bottom triangle nested for loop
        for (n1 = 16; n1 > 2; n1 -= 2)
        {
            for (n2 = 2; n2 <= n1; n2 += 2)
            {
                Console.Write("{0} ", n2);
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
```

Full code with change color :

```
   static bool _isRedColor = true;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int n1, n2;

        // Top Triangle nested for loop
        for (n1 = 2; n1 <= 18; n1 += 2)
        {
            _isRedColor = true;
            for (n2 = 2; n2 <= n1; n2 += 2)
            {
                SetConsoleColor();
                Console.Write("{0} ", n2);
                //n2++;
            }
            //n1++;
            Console.WriteLine();
        }

        // Bottom triangle nested for loop
        for (n1 = 16; n1 > 2; n1 -= 2)
        {
            _isRedColor = true;
            for (n2 = 2; n2 <= n1; n2 += 2)
            {
                SetConsoleColor();
                Console.Write("{0} ", n2);
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }

    private static void SetConsoleColor()
    {
        if (_isRedColor)
        {
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkRed;
            _isRedColor = !_isRedColor;
        }
        else
        {
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkGreen;
            _isRedColor = !_isRedColor;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question was interesting so that I have made a try, would like to share my findings here with a [working example in fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/qU5JAM), please note I have used few additional variables as well as  renamed existing variables hope that it won't mislead you. Please go through the following lines and let me know if you need any clarifications

```
int loopLimit = 18;
int outerLoopCounter, innerLoopCounter = 2, upperBoudIterator = 2;

// Top Triangle nested for loop
for (outerLoopCounter = 0; outerLoopCounter <= 18; outerLoopCounter++)
{
    innerLoopCounter = 2;
    while (innerLoopCounter <= upperBoudIterator)
    {
        if (innerLoopCounter <= loopLimit)
            Console.Write("{0} ", innerLoopCounter);               
        innerLoopCounter += 2;
    };
    if (innerLoopCounter > loopLimit)
        loopLimit -= 2;
    upperBoudIterator += 2;
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So I tried this as a scholarly exercise, and here's my try at it. Using the method and property I mentioned in the comments, you can pull this off with a single loop-nested-loop pair:

```
int max = 18;
int cursorX = 0;
int count, digits;

for (int i = 2; i <= max; i += 2)
{
    count = max - i + 1;
    digits = i.ToString().Length;
    Console.ForegroundColor = (i % 4 == 0) ? ConsoleColor.Red : ConsoleColor.Green;

    for (int y = 0; y < count; y++)
    {
        Console.SetCursorPosition(cursorX, y + (i / 2) - 1);
        Console.Write(i);
    }

    cursorX += digits + 1;
}
```

Result:

[image]